# How to present reply chains on a mobile/condensed interface?

Tags: usability, gui-design, usability-testing, comments, community

Take a website such as [reddit](http://reddit.com) where users can reply to a post, and then users can reply to that reply, etc.

[image]

I'm building a mobile application that deals with a similar situation with nested replies. However, I'm really stuck on how to implement it efficiently.

Mobile screens have such a narrow width. I feel this "indentation" pattern encounters problems very quickly. (Can't show very many comments deep, text boxes get narrower and narrower, etc.)

Does anyone have any alternative ideas on how I could implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is a tricky one, there's no easy way around it.  One of the more popular comment services these days is [Disqus](http://disqus.com) - their comments are responsive.  It's not perfect, really only handles up to about four levels of indentation.  [Example](http://disqus.com).

The other option, if you think you are going to get more and more levels of replies like this would be to just minimise and have one level show with the option to 'Show Sub-Level' as a CTA (with better copy).

I don't think it's necessary to display all this content on mobile anyways.  If you were to display all sub-level comments, the user will have to do a hell of a lot of scrolling to get to the next relevant content, even using Disqus - this isn't a great user experience.